# Bugs in solr multi word synonym filter

Tags: solr, synonym

I have a problem with multi-word synonyms. the synonym.txt file is like this:

```
.
.
.
KTP,kartu tanda penduduk
KUD,koperasi unit desa
KUHAP,kitab undang-undang hukum acara pidana
KUHD,kitab undang-undang hukum dagang
KUHP,kitab undang-undang hukum pidana
KUHPer,kitab undang-undang hukum perdata
KUKM,koperasi dan usaha kecil dan menengah
KY,komisi yudisial
LAN,lembaga administrasi negara
.
.
.
```

this file contains many abbreviation.

When I query the keyword "KUHP", "KUHAP", "KUHD", "KUHPer" in field named "header" in solr, It is only returned result with that keywords only.
so if I query "KUHP" the result is only:

1. "KUHP is a new thing"
2. "Repel the KUHP"
3. "KUHP amend"

but there are another document like "kitab undang-undang hukum pidana starting", "stopping kitab undang-undang hukum pidana" which its synonym of "KUHP" that not in the result.

And also I checked in query analyzer, the synonym filter is worked well for the "KUHP", "KUHAP", "KUHD", "KUHPer".

it only happen in those 4 words. When I search another word like "KY", "LAN", "KTP", it return the exact result and also with the synonym.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: could you show your schema.xml?